# Modify the sensitivity of the joysticks of a PS3 controller in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Right now I am working in a project and I am testing it with my PS3 controller and some of the mechanics of the game is to dodge an enemy attack if the player moves the left stick once to the left or to the right, up or down. And if the player moves the stick twice, the character will do a roll. But the sentitive that the stick has is too high that the player needs to do a very fast movement to dodge and if it is not fast enough it just rolls and keep rolling if the player hold the stick in one direction.

So here is the question:
How can I change the sensitivity of the stick?

I tried changing the value in the Input Manager but it doesn't work (if I put a higher number the problem stays and if I put a lower number it does'nt work).

[Input manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr7lH.png)

This is the code that I did to do the rolls:

```
#region Forward
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") <= -0.1 && forwardRoll)
        {
            if (timeToRoll > 0)
            {
                animatorController.SetBool("RollForward", true);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
                animatorController.SetBool("RollForward", false);

                forwardRoll = false;
            }
            else
            {
                forwardRoll = false;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") <= -0.1 && !forwardRoll)
        {
            forwardRoll = true;
            timeToRoll = 1f;
        }
        #endregion
```

*This is for the Forward Roll, is the same for the other directions*

Note: the `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` returns a  0.1 as a higher value or -0.1 as the lower in the Y axis, the same for the X axis.

Thank you all, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

All the values for an Axis are in interval [-1, 1]

so if you want to modify the sensivity of stick you could (for example) divide the zone in 10 or more parts and modify the return value used:

for example to add less senivity for an axis: you could do that:

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("what you want") ;
if ( x > -0.1 && x < 0.1)  // less sensivity at deadzone
    x = 0;
else if (x > -0.3 && x < -0.2)
    x = -0.1;
else if
    and so on

then you use the value x to inject in your program and not the value of Input.GetAxis
```

so you could calibrate each zone with the value desired

you could do have a linear function different at each zone

or apply a new function to the Axis.

for example, you have lot of joystick curve [HERE](https://github.com/achilleas-k/fs2open.github.com/blob/joystick_curves/joy_curve_notes/new_curves.md)

and if you choose the first curve

f(x) = x*(s/9)+(x^5)*(9-s)/9  with s = 0, you have:

f(x) = x^5

for x in [0, 1] you have f(x) in [0,1]

for x in [-1, 0] you have f(x) in [-1,0],

so in program you could write:

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("what you want");
x = Mathf.Pow( x, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
If player presses an axis... Start courutine.... Check in courutine for a brief time if value was zero and then if it became a plus or minus number again before time runs out... If so do barrel roll if the value was not changed in specified time then just dodge... Your issue is not sensitivity... Is logic... Sorry if i dont show any code :)